# Extending metrics from $M =\mathbb{T}^2 \times (-\pi , \pi)$ to $ \mathbb{T}^3$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry

I would like to know of a similar result for the below but for the torus:

$\textbf{Cylinder to sphere rule:}$ Let $0< w \leq \infty$, and let $g$ be a metric on the topological
cylinder $(-w, w) \times  S^n$ of the form
$$g = \phi(z)^2 dz^2 + \psi(z)^2 g_{can}$$
where $\phi,\psi : (-w, w) \to \mathbb{R_+}$ and $g_{can}$ is the canonical round metric of radius $1$ on $S^n$. Then $g$ extends to a smooth metric on $S^{n+1}$ if and only if

$$ \int^w_{-w}\phi(r)dr < \infty$$
$$ \lim_{z \to \pm w} \psi(z) = 0 $$
$$\lim_{z \to \pm w} \frac{\psi'(z)}{\phi(z)} = \mp1 $$
and
$$ \lim_{z \to \pm w} \frac{d^{2k}\psi(z)}{ds^{2k}} = 0  $$

for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, where $ds$ is the element of arc length induced by $\phi$.

Well, I tried to reformulate and it was like this:

Notation:
$$S^r =\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 = r^2 \}$$ $$S^R = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 = R^2 \}$$ $$S^a = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 = a^2 \}$$ $\mathbb{T}^2 = S^R \times S^r \texttt{ with } R>r>0$ $\mathbb{T}^3 = S^R \times S^r \times S^a \texttt{ with } R>r>0 \texttt{ and } a> R + r  $

$\textbf{Reformulation:}$ Let $M =  \mathbb{T}^2  \times (-\pi , \pi)$ be a manifold with the metric:

$$g = r^2 dx^2 + (R + r.cos(x))^2 dy^2 + \theta(x,y,z)^2dz^2$$
and $\theta: (-\pi, \pi)^3 \to \mathbb{R_+}$ so $g$ extends to a metric in $\mathbb{T}^3$ if and only if

$$ |{\int_A\theta(x,y,z)dA}| < \infty$$
   $$ \lim_{(x,y,z) \to \pm (\pi, \pi, \pi)} \theta(x,y,z) = a+r-R $$

where $A = (-\pi, \pi)^3 $.

Explanation about the formulation and some ideas: When a fix the metric

$g = r^2 dx^2 + (R + r.cos(x))^2 dy^2$ in $\mathbb{T}^2$ and make such extension, then I would like to know if the metric in $\mathbb{T}^3$ must be like this

$g = r^2 dx^2 + (R + r.cos(x))^2 dy^2 + (a + (R + r.cos(x))cos(y))^2dz^2$?

and, if so, the conditions above are sufficient?

In addition, suppose that $g$ extends to a metric in $ \mathbb{T}^3$, then for any parametrization $f$ we have $\langle \partial_x f,  \partial_x f \rangle= r^2 $, $\langle \partial_y f,  \partial_y f \rangle= (R + rcos(x))^2 $  and $\langle \partial_z f,  \partial_z f \rangle= \theta(x,y,z) ^2 $ so $||\partial_x f|| = r$, $||\partial_y f|| = (R + rcos(x))$ and $||\partial_y f|| = \theta(x,y,z) $. Now

$$ |\int_A\theta(x,y,z)dA| \leq \int_A |\theta(x,y,z)|dA = \int_A ||\partial_y f|| < \infty $$

Is that right? 
thanks in advance!

Comment: How you've written it it's confusing which coordinate you're closing off: maybe you should write $M = \mathbb{T}^2 \times (-\pi, \pi)$ instead.

Comment: You are right. Now looks better..

Answer (score 1):

The integral condition in the first example is just saying that the total arclength is finite- the appropriate integral condition for you is $\int_{-\pi}^\pi \theta dz$ being finite.

The other condition for a smooth closing is easier to understand in your situation than in the closing-to-$S^{n+1}$ situation that you cited, because here none of the factors in the coordinates you've written degenerate to $0$.  What you need is that $\theta$ extends to a (strictly positive) function on $T^3$, which is $C^{\infty}$ if you want the metric to be $C^{\infty}$.  Basically just take the conditions for a periodic function.

Comment: Let me know if I understand. Are you saying that would be much more aproprieted if it were so: Let $M =  \mathbb{T}^2  \times (-\pi , \pi)$ be a manifold with the metric: 

$$g = r^2 dx^2 + (R + r.cos(x))^2 dy^2 + \theta(x,y,z)^2dz^2$$
and $\theta: (-\pi, \pi)^3 \to \mathbb{R_+}$ so $g$ extends to a metric in $\mathbb{T}^3$ if and only if $g$ extends to a periodic function on $\mathbb{T}^3$ such that 
 
 
   $$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\theta(x,y,z)dz < \infty$$
  
 



where $A = (-\pi, \pi)^3 $?

Comment: To me there is some issues like that: How may I extends $\theta$ to $\mathbb{T}^3$ if $(\pi, \pi)^3 \not \subset \mathbb{T}^3$?

Comment: When you said $\theta: (-\pi, \pi)^3 \to \mathbb{R}_+$ you seemed to be implicitly identifying $\mathbb{T}$ with $[-\pi, \pi]/(-\pi \sim \pi)$.  With that identification we can say $(-\pi, \pi)^3 \subset \mathbb{T}^3$.

Comment: Can you explain me better why $\theta$ has to be necessarily periodic?